# TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath Not Being Called

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview

On a UITableView, I used Custom Cells with this code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];    

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);


    if(deltaX < kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY < kMaximumVariance&&!swiped){
        //do something 
        NSLog(@"Tapped %d",indexRow);
        //return YES;
    } else if(deltaX < kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY < kMaximumVariance&&swiped) {
        swiped = FALSE;
    }

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];    

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);


    if(deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance){
        //do something 
        NSLog(@"Swiped %d",indexRow);
        gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];
        swiped = TRUE;
    }
    else if(deltaY >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaX <= kMaximumVariance){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Before I added this, didSelectRowAtIndexPath was being called, however, now it is not. I can comment out the section and it works fine. Anyone know a way to fix this?

EDIT: Posting the working code

Customcell.h

```
#define kMinimumGestureLength  30
#define kMaximumVariance   5
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel *primaryLabel;
    UILabel *secondaryLabel;
    UIImageView *myImageView;


    CGPoint gestureStartPoint;
    int indexRow;
    BOOL swiped;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *primaryLabel;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *secondaryLabel;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *myImageView;

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"


@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize primaryLabel,secondaryLabel,myImageView;

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;
    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+10 ,0, 50, 50);
    myImageView.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+70 ,5, 200, 25);
    primaryLabel.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+70 ,30, 100, 15);
    secondaryLabel.frame = frame;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier indexd:(int)indexd {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code
        primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        primaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        secondaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        secondaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        secondaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8];
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:secondaryLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
        indexRow = indexd;
    }
    swiped = false;
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];
   // [super touchesbegan];
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];    

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);


    if(deltaX < kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY < kMaximumVariance&&!swiped){
        //do something 
        NSLog(@"Tapped %d",indexRow);
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        //return YES;
    } else if(deltaX < kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY < kMaximumVariance&&swiped) {
        swiped = FALSE;
    }
    //[super touchesEnded];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];    

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);


    if(deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance){
        //do something 
        NSLog(@"Swiped %d",indexRow);
        gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];
        swiped = TRUE;
        //[self.superview.dataSource editCell];
    }
    else if(deltaY >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaX <= kMaximumVariance){
        //do something
    }
    //[super touchesMoved];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think you need to call the super methods in order to continue to have the default behavior.

```
[super touchesBegan:...];

[super touchesEnded:...];

[super touchesMoved:...];
```

Each in it's own method.

Comment: This works pretty well. The one thing Im still having trouble with is when the Custom Cell is selected, it is highlighted blue even if touchesended is not super'd. Any way I can manually deselect it?

Comment: By deselect it, you mean not turn blue but still get the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?
In this case I suggest a different approach. Instead of using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, use `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and return nil from it. This way, you catch the selection event and by returning `nil` you are canceling the selection as far as the table view is concerned (it will not turn blue). Read the documentation for `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` as it allows you to do some pretty cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932151/handling-touchesbegan-in-uitableviewcell-disables-didselectrowatindexpath). try calling the parent methods with `[super touchesbegan]` et al.